# Is it possible to resume an interupted mysql import from a backup file?

Tags: mysql, restore, import

I created a backup file of my database with phpMyAdmin and checked the following data dump option:

include column names in every INSERT statement 
      Example: INSERT INTO tbl_name (col_A,col_B,col_C) VALUES (1,2,3)

For now I get an error because some tables rows at the beginning of the import already exist, results of the incomplete import.

Is it possible to resume the import of this file, which has already been started but not finished ? I would like to do it without deleting the database content, nor modifying too much of the backup file, is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't worked with PHPAdmin for a very long time, but it should be able to generate `insert ... ignore` instead of just `insert`. If my memory serves me well, there is a checkbox 'using insert ignore' on export/backup page.

Comment: Indeed, your memory is good. I checked the 'using insert ignore' on my database export and it worked as intended. Thanks !